# нужно чтобы при не правильном подтверждении email заново писалось подтвердите email пока изначально введеный email не совпал

Tags: python

```py
w = input ('Введите своё имя ')
s = input ('Введите свой адрес электронной почты ')
e = input ('Потвердите свой адрес электронной почты ')
if (s == e): print ('Успешно')
if (s != e): print('Адреса не совпадают, перезапустите программу')'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поместите в бесконечный цикл?
Если совпадает, остановите его, если нет, выведите сообщение и запросите ввести почту заного.

```
    while(True):
    if (s==e):
        print("Успешно")
        break
    else:
        print("Почта должна совпадать!")
        e = input("Подтвердите почту: ")
```